# Dynamically registering and unregistering Nancy routes/modules

Tags: nancy

We have a situation where our app has a number of modules that implement an api. Each of these modules has a dependency that in turn depends on a data directory path being properly configured. These modules should not even be constructed until this path is configured.

We also have a module that implements the setting and validation of the configuration, including configuring the aforementioned path.

We would like to somehow 'disable' the data modules until such time as the config can be confirmed. The config would be confirmed by, for example, at start up we check that the data directory exists and is valid. Additionally when a user saves changes through the config module we would again do that confirmation. To recap, the user sets the data directory and then the data modules all get enabled. When the user sets an invalid data directory (or we start up and the existing one is invalid) the modules all get disabled.

We tried registering a handler on the `pipelines.BeforeRequest` but it didn't help. We're actually failing much earlier, when Nancy is instantiating our modules as part of populating a `RouteCache`. We need to prevent this instantiation until we can confirm we're configured.

It seems like we ought to be able to say "use this set of modules when some condition is true, and use this other set when the condition is false." How does one go about something like this in Nancy?

Answer (score 0):

If all these modules you are referring to implement the same API (i.e. define the same set of `Method` + `Pattern` + `Action` handlers) then perhaps you should use just one module to handle the requests for all of them, and use a capture segment variable (e.g. `"/{path}/api/operation/"`) in your module's pattern to identify which path (i.e. data directory) you are referring to.

Then, in the body of the action, you could check whether the conditions you need are satisfied. Something like this:

```cs
Get["/app/{directory}/api/status"] = parameters => {
    var dataDirectory = parameters.directory;
    // Do whatever condition checks you need with the dataDirectory value
    // and return the appropriate HTTP status code if they are not met,
    // otherwise continue handling the request
    return HttpStatus.OK;
}
```

Another approach would be (again if using a single module to handle all these requests) to use a custom route parameter constraint (see https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Defining-routes#custom-constraints).
In this case if your conditions are not met, the route will not be hit at all.